# Aggregate and count identical rows in r

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

I have a data.frame that looks like this (however with a larger number of columns and rows):
[image]

I want to sum the rows that have all columns identical and create last column "count", in order to get something like this:
[image]

Thank you for help!

data:

```
structure(list(Gene = c("A", "A", "B", "C"), `Cell 1` = c(2, 
2, 3, 4), `Cell 2` = c(2, 2, 3, 4), `Cell 3` = c(2, 2, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL terms, you can count rows grouping by all columns and join the result with the initial data.frame.

I recommend using data.table package.

```
df=data.frame(a=c(1,1,2,3,4,4,4),b=c("a","a","b","b","e","e","f"))

library(data.table)

# convert df to data.table
df=as.data.table(df)

# aggregate df grouping by all columns
clmns=colnames(df)
row_multiplicity=df[,.N,by=clmns]

#join/merge with initial data.frame
new_df=merge(df,row_multiplicity)
```

Answer (score 2):

Toy example, not the most elegant way

```
mtcars2=mtcars[c(1,1,2,3),]

do.call(rbind,
  by(
    mtcars2,
    mtcars2,
    function(x){
      data.frame(unique(x),"Count"=nrow(x))
    })
)

               mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb Count
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     1
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4     2
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4     1
```

**Edit:** OP provided data

```
df=structure(list(Gene = c("A", "A", "B", "C"), `Cell 1` = c(2, 
                                                          2, 3, 4), `Cell 2` = c(2, 2, 3, 4), `Cell 3` = c(2, 2, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                       -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
do.call(rbind,
  by(df,
     df,
     function(x){
       data.frame(unique(x),"Count"=nrow(x))
     }
  )
)

  Gene Cell.1 Cell.2 Cell.3 Count
1    A      2      2      2     2
3    B      3      3      3     1
4    C      4      4      4     1
```

Comment: this is the message I get: Error in tapply(seq_len(8694L), list(MS = c(18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L,  : 
  total number of levels >= 2^31

Comment: @Jelica It seems that your actual data and the data you provided are different. Is your actual data much different?

Comment: In my actual data I have 14 variables and more than 8000 rows

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, but here is a `dplyr` solution that relies on all columns being identical to be added to  the `Count` column. This groups by all columns, adds `Count` column with the length of each "group" (i.e., `n()`), and then ungroups and removes duplicate rows using `distinct()`

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(across(everything())) %>%
  mutate(Count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct()
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  Gene  Cell_1 Cell_2 Cell_3 Count
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1 A          2      2      2     2
2 B          3      3      3     1
3 C          4      4      4     1
```

Or, a possible `data.table` solution using the same logic:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)
df1[, Count := .N, by = names(df1)]
unique(df1)
```

Or, a base solution substituting grouping with indexing data.frame-wide duplicates:

```
df1$Count = duplicated(df1) + 1
df1[!duplicated(df1[names(df1) != "Count"], fromLast = TRUE), ]
```

**Data**:

```
df1 = data.frame(Gene = c("A", "A", "B", "C"))
df1[paste0("Cell_", 1:3)] = c(2, 2:4)
```

Comment: in this solution, where goes a name of data.frame?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, can you explain more?

Comment: this is the message I get: Error in across(everything()) : could not find function "across" and I have installed dplyr

Comment: I am guessing `packageVersion("dplyr")` is < 1.0.0. In older versions of `dplyr` you can use `group_by_all()`

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr package:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% add_count(Gene, name = 'Count') %>% group_by(Gene) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Gene [3]
  Gene  `Cell 1` `Cell 2` `Cell 3` Count
  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
1 A            2        2        2     2
2 B            3        3        3     1
3 C            4        4        4     1
>
```

Data used:

```
structure(list(Gene = c("A", "A", "B", "C"), `Cell 1` = c(2, 
2, 3, 4), `Cell 2` = c(2, 2, 3, 4), `Cell 3` = c(2, 2, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this code

```
df=structure(list(Gene = c("A", "A", "B", "C"), `Cell 1` = c(2, 
                                                          2, 3, 4), `Cell 2` = c(2, 2, 3, 4), `Cell 3` = c(2, 2, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                       -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df1=unique(df)    #Store Unique Rows    
df2=df[duplicated(df),]    #Store Duplicated Rows

df3=df1    #Copy unique Dataframe into new dataframe    
df3['count']=1    #Create and assign with default value    


for(i in 1:nrow(df2))    #Duplicated Rows
  
{
  
  for(j in 1:nrow(df1))    #Unique Rows
    
  {
    
    if (all(df1[j,] == df2[i,]))    #Check all columns data is same
      
    {
      
      df3[j,'count'] <- df3[j,'count']+1   # Increase count to one
      
    }
    
    
  }
  
}
```